# D3 Bubbles with all possible relationships

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, d3.js, jointjs

I have an array of 8 Objects. i want to render a bubble for each object, and each object can have a one or multiple transactions with one or multiple bubbles,in this case i need to render one or multiple arrows(with text on top) to the corresponding bubbles. there is a possibility for the circular relation ship as well (ex: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1). i did it jointjs, but the problem is rendering bubble is not in our control, if we implement in d3 then we can give gravity feature, which is good.

can you please help me in implementing this.

Best Regards,
Saran

Comment: Please, show your code with all you've done so far, and we can give you some help.

Comment: I followed in the following links first i did it, but the problem is we wont be having a control on rendering bubble  the links are 1) http://jointjs.com/demos/fsa 2) http://gojs.net/latest/samples/stateChart.html)        But using d3.js i could not do it, i didnt find any example.